# How to display statistics as text in a graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, cdf

I am using `cdfplot` in matlab to plot the empirical CDF of certain quantities.

```
[h,stats]=cdfplot(quantity)
```

Now `stats` returns me a structure having min, max, mean etc. I want these values to be displayed as text in the graph.

I have lot of similar graphs to plot and do not want to do it manually.

Comment: You can use the function `text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put a text on a plot you use the `text` function. Here is a quick [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html) on one plot:

```
y = evrnd(0,3,100,1);
[h, stats] = cdfplot(y);
hold on
x = -20:0.1:10;
f = evcdf(x,0,3);
plot(x,f,'m')
legend('Empirical','Theoretical','Location','NW')
stat_type =  {'min: ';'max: ';'mean: ';'median: ';'std: '}; % make titles
stat_val = num2str(struct2array(stats).'); % convert stats to string
text(-15,0.7,stat_type) % <-- here
text(-11,0.7,stat_val) % <-- and here
hold off
```

This will give:

[image: CDF_text]

and you can use it inside a loop to do it for all the graphs.

The tricky thing is to define where to put the text on the graph. Here I choose (-15,0.7) and (-11,0.7) as a fixed points where I know there is no data. You should look at your plots, and find the correct place for that.